# FFmpeg image to video conversion error: [image2] Opening file for reading

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am running ffmpeg on an AWS Lambda instance. The Lambda function takes an input image and transcodes it into a video segment using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/photo-SNRUR7ZS13.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 7.00 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280x720 /tmp/output.mp4
```

I am seeing inconsistent behavior where sometimes the output video is shorter than the specified duration. This happens inconsistently to random images. The same exact image sometimes renders correctly, and sometimes is cut short.

This behavior only happens on Lambda. I am not able to replicate this on my local computer, or on a dedicated EC2 instance with the same environment that runs on lambda.

I noticed that when the output video is short, the ffmpeg log is different. The main difference are repeated `[image2 @ 0x4b11140] Opening '/tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg' for reading` lines. See ffmpeg logs below.

Normal execution with the correct output video length:

```
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/photo-SNRUR7ZS13.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 7.00 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280x720 /tmp/video-TMB6RNO0EE.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89773-g7fcbebbeaf-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-11) 20171206
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from '/tmp/photo-SNRUR7ZS13.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18703 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 687x860 [SAR 200:200 DAR 687:860], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x5837900] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] using SAR=1477/3287
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] 264 - core 155 r61 b00bcaf - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/video-TMB6RNO0EE.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 6183:13760 DAR 687:860], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   49 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=-00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=   69 fps= 66 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=0.728x    
frame=   89 fps= 57 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=0.998x    
frame=  109 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.36 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=1.14x    
frame=  129 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.22x    
frame=  148 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.92 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.27x    
frame=  168 fps= 47 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.72 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.31x    
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=  175 fps= 39 q=-1.0 Lsize=      94kB time=00:00:06.88 bitrate= 112.2kbits/s speed=1.54x    
video:91kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.161261%
Input file #0 (/tmp/photo-SNRUR7ZS13.jpg):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 176 packets read (16459168 bytes); 176 frames decoded; 
  Total: 176 packets (16459168 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/tmp/video-TMB6RNO0EE.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 175 frames encoded; 175 packets muxed (93507 bytes); 
  Total: 175 packets (93507 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] frame I:1     Avg QP:14.33  size: 73084
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] frame P:44    Avg QP:14.09  size:   302
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] frame B:130   Avg QP:23.31  size:    50
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] consecutive B-frames:  0.6%  1.1%  0.0% 98.3%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] mb I  I16..4:  3.3% 84.5% 12.1%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  3.2%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.7%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.6%  L0:31.2% L1:68.8% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] 8x8 transform intra:84.5% inter:98.8%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 95.1% 63.9% 51.6% inter: 0.1% 0.6% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26% 21%  4% 49%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 27% 21%  3%  5%  6%  6%  4%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 36% 10%  4%  7%  5%  6%  2%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 29% 16%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] ref P L0: 96.5%  0.0%  3.3%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] ref B L0: 42.4% 57.6%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] ref B L1: 97.0%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x51c2340] kb/s:106.08
```

Log from a short video:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -y -loop 1 -i /tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg -t 15.00 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=h=ih:w='if(gt(a,16/9),ih*16/9,iw)':y=0:x='if(gt(a,16/9),(ow-iw)/2,0)'[tmp];[tmp]scale=-1:4000,crop=w=iw:h='min(iw*9/16,ih)':x=0:y='0.17*ih-((t/15.00)*min(0.17*ih,(ih-oh)/6))',trim=duration=15.00[tmp1];[tmp1]zoompan=z='if(lte(pzoom,1.0),1.15,max(1.0,pzoom-0.0005))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1,setsar=sar=1:1[animated];[animated]fade=out:st=12.00:d=3.00:c=#000000[animated]" -map "[animated]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -y /tmp/video-QB1JCDT021.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89773-g7fcbebbeaf-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-11) 20171206
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 7.100 / 56. 7.100
libavcodec 58. 9.100 / 58. 9.100
libavformat 58. 3.100 / 58. 3.100
libavdevice 58. 0.100 / 58. 0.100
libavfilter 7. 11.101 / 7. 11.101
libswscale 5. 0.101 / 5. 0.101
libswresample 3. 0.101 / 3. 0.101
libpostproc 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100
Input #0, image2, from '/tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 373617 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1936x2592 [SAR 72:72 DAR 121:162], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> crop
fade -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x4d63b40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x4df7340] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x50e97c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x50e97c0] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
[libx264 @ 0x4b17480] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x4b17480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x4b17480] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x4b17480] 264 - core 155 r61 b00bcaf - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/video-QB1JCDT021.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder : Lavf58.3.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[swscaler @ 0x5bd0380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
debug=1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x4b11140] Opening '/tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg' for reading
[AVIOContext @ 0x4b6ecc0] Statistics: 1868086 bytes read, 0 seeks
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=1868084
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=1868082
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=db avail_size_in_buf=1868064
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] index=0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] qscale[0]: 0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=db avail_size_in_buf=1867995
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] index=1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] qscale[1]: 1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=1867926
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] sof0: picture: 1936x2592
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 0 1:1 id: 0 quant:0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] pix fmt id 11111100
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867907
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=0 index=0 nb_codes=11
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 30 bytes (240 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867875
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=1 index=0 nb_codes=242
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 82 bytes (656 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867791
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=0 index=1 nb_codes=8
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 27 bytes (216 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867762
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=1 index=1 nb_codes=241
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 51 bytes (408 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] escaping removed 7149 bytes
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=da avail_size_in_buf=1867709
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 2
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 1860559 bytes (14884468 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] decode frame unused 0 bytes
[swscaler @ 0x5bd42c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x4b11140] Opening '/tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg' for reading
[AVIOContext @ 0x4b6ecc0] Statistics: 1868086 bytes read, 0 seeks
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=1868084
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=1868082
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=db avail_size_in_buf=1868064
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] index=0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] qscale[0]: 0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=db avail_size_in_buf=1867995
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] index=1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] qscale[1]: 1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=1867926
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] sof0: picture: 1936x2592
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 0 1:1 id: 0 quant:0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] pix fmt id 11111100
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867907
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=0 index=0 nb_codes=11
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 30 bytes (240 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867875
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=1 index=0 nb_codes=242
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 82 bytes (656 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867791
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=0 index=1 nb_codes=8
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 27 bytes (216 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=1867762
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] class=1 index=1 nb_codes=241
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 51 bytes (408 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] escaping removed 7149 bytes
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=da avail_size_in_buf=1867709
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 1
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] component: 2
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker parser used 1860559 bytes (14884468 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
[mjpeg @ 0x4b14940] decode frame unused 0 bytes
[swscaler @ 0x5bd8200] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
...
...
...
```

As requested, here is a [link to the full log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/wellofmemories.catandcastle.com/0a332004fbb849948cbb01787dc8b6ab.log). In this log - ffmpeg renders only 323 out of 375 frames.

The `Opening '/tmp/photo-2HD2Z3UN3W.jpg'` segment repeats many many times until it finally renders out a short video. Does anyone have insight into why it keeps opening the image file? This must have something to do with the underlying issue.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Mulvya here is a link to the full log for a short video: https://s3.amazonaws.com/wellofmemories.catandcastle.com/0a332004fbb849948cbb01787dc8b6ab.log

Comment: Remove `-loop 1` and add `loop=375:1:0,setpts=N/25/TB` filters before the 1st crop filter, and check.

Comment: Wow!! Problem solved! Thank you so much @Mulvya! Do you know why the error inconsistently happened only to some photos before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-loop` option applied to an image (sequence) forces ffmpeg to open and decode the files afresh each time the input is looped. So, in this case, ffmpeg has to open the file over the network repeatedly. My guess is that some of the HTTP requests aren't fulfilled fast enough, and ffmpeg drops those received frames.

After dropping `-loop 1` and switching to loop filter: `loop=NB_LOOPS:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB`, ffmpeg opens the image only once, and then clones the decoded frame in its buffer. This gives the expected result.